# Integrate SDK to android application

Tags: android, authentication, sdk, integration, fingerprint

I am beginner in android development.I want to integrate a fingerprint verification SDK to my app.I have an external hardware to detect the fingerprint.How can we integrate it and use the functions in the SDK in my project.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Google has announced a generic fingerprint API for Android that can be utilised by any custom apps for authorisation and not just the native Google apps. It looks like the future is just getting brighter!

Taken from the Android Developers page linked below:

"To authenticate users via fingerprint scan, get an instance of the new FingerprintManager class and call the authenticate() method."

However you must also include this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

If you want to find out more information then visit this URL and scroll down to Authentication:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#fingerprint-authentication